# Yes or No instead of True or False in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, boolean

In Knockout is there a clean way to display a boolean property from my view model to show 'Yes' or 'No' instead of True / False. Sometimes the property is undefined so this should also show No.

Currently using :

```
<td data-bind="text: isAvailable ? 'Yes' : 'No'"></td>
```

Must be a better way.

Comment: if(!bool || typeof bool == undefined) bool='No'; else bool='Yes'; ? Don't see why you would replace fully functional boolean values though.

Comment: Apologies @JazzCat. Hope my edit makes clarifies my question. You can see what I am trying to achieve from the markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this custom bindingHandler,

```
ko.bindingHandlers.YesNo = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // defaults to false
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || false; 

        if (val)
            $(element).text("Yes");
        else
            $(element).text("No");
    }
}
```

Use it like so,

```
<td data-bind="YesNo: isAvailable"></td>
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for guiding me in the right direction. I amended your code to declare the variables correctly and remove unused variables - but I see your thinking and this is a very clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you define `isAvailable` as observable you can easily achieve it by:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/farizazmi/04pw9got/1/)

**ViewModel**

```
var viewModel = function()
{
   var self = this;

   self.isAvailable = ko.observable(false);
};
```

**View**

```
<td data-bind="text: $root.isAvailable() ? 'Yes' : 'No'"></td>
```

p/s: don't forget to use `()` when dealing with observable value